# Using Native Android Bluetooth Support for Codename

Tags: android, codenameone

Need help with a working example of native android bluetooth support for codenameone apps. I have one working in android but having a problem integrating with codenameone.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have working code in Android already, you just need to create a Native Interface to handle the API calls and callbacks you need. You'll be able to use most of your Android code, a few modifications will be needed to strip out the parts that control the UI. Check the developer guide, it discusses this. I believe that there's also a tutorial video.

There is also a CN1Lib or extension for Bluetooth Low Energy, if that's what you're developing.

Comment: If I could just get an example with the modification and integration

Comment: Is this for Low Energy? There is an example on the page with the CN1 extensions https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone

Comment: Not for low energy